# debugging java android multi thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, debugging

I'm new to multi-thread programming. I develop apps for smartphones on Android Studio for API 16 these days. Searching help on how to pause my program, I've found sleep() is not good due to threading. Please tell me:

1. Is there "real" multi tasking with Android on multicore processors (maybe depending on API version)?
2. Is there (do not know correct term) pausing one thread to start working on other multitasking on Android?
3. If yes to 1 or/and 2 - how to debug the code - will Studio open new window for new method call (thread start) - myself have not seen that yet? Maybe other debug tools?
4. during run - if I click on say button with listener when previous run on listener (same or other method) is not finished - will it start to process the method in parallel to first?
5. same question if first run is postponed via postDelayed?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

As asynchronous processing is a vitality for most application these days, Android does support `MultiTasking`.

Android does support Multi threading just the same way in Java, and every app has a UI thread to handle input events from the user and modify the user interface. This thread is known as Main Thread. And at times, you can't use everything on the main thread, in that case , Android provides you mainly 2 ways to implement concurrency:

- Handler
- AsyncTask

Using Threads, are not recommended in Android, because of the following reasons:

- Synchronization with the main thread, if you post back results to the
  user interface
- No default for canceling the thread
- No default thread pooling
- No default for handling configuration changes in Android

In most cases, `AsyncTask` is the best option , You can read more about `AsyncTask` [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Also, if you want to know more about concurrency in Android, refer [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html)